# libreoffice installs stuck on upgrade to 19.10

Tags: apt, upgrade, 19.10

I'm attempting to upgrade to ubuntu 19.10 but seem to have messed up my dependencies somewhere along the way.

I type

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

output:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

Then

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

gives

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libreoffice-base libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-math
  libreoffice-report-builder-bin libreoffice-sdbc-mysql
  libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 6 not to upgrade.
```

This is the same also if one uses the --with-new-pkgs flag. So I try to install one of these, for example, libreoffice base:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-base
...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libreoffice-base : Depends: libreoffice-base-core (=1:6.2.8~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 1:6.2.7-0ubuntu0.19.04.1 is to be installed
                Depends: libreoffice-base-drivers (= 1:6.2.8~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 1:6.2.7-0ubuntu0.19.04.1 is to be installed
                Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.2.8~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 1:6.2.7-0ubuntu0.19.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Going down the rabbit hole a little further, I attempted to downgrade libreoffice-core:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-core=1:6.2.8~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libboost-date-time1.58.0 but it is not installable
                Depends: libboost-iostreams1.58.0 but it is not installable
                Depends: libboost-locale1.58.0 but it is not installable
                Depends: libhunspell-1.3-0 (>= 1.3.3) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I'm getting lost at this point, and would appreciate any help anyone can offer. Many thanks!

Edit: Requested outputs:

```
apt-cache policy libreoffice-base
libreoffice-base:
  Installed: 1:6.2.7-0ubuntu0.19.04.1
  Candidate: 1:6.2.8~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  Version table:  1:6.2.8~rc2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 500
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1:6.2.7-0ubuntu0.19.04.1 500
500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/universe amd64
Packages
500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security/universe amd64
Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu2 500
    500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/universe amd64 Packages
```

and

```
grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/ lsb3.2 main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ekozincew-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.distUpgrade:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ekozincew/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ekozincew-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ekozincew/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco partner
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sagemath.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/x2go.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/x2go/stable/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:# deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.distUpgrade:deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list.save:deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-security-sources.list.distUpgrade:deb-src http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/x2go.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/x2go/stable/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sstp-network-manager.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/eivnaes/network-manager-sstp/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ekozincew-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ekozincew/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ekozincew-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ekozincew/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris.list.save:# deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04/ ./
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/puppetlabs-pc1.list:# deb http://apt.puppetlabs.com bionic PC1 # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/puppetlabs-pc1.list:# deb-src http://apt.puppetlabs.com xenial PC1
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list.save:deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list.distUpgrade:# deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/puppetlabs-pc1.list.save:deb http://apt.puppetlabs.com xenial PC1
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/puppetlabs-pc1.list.save:# deb-src http://apt.puppetlabs.com xenial PC1
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-sources.list.distUpgrade:deb-src http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list.distUpgrade:deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu cosmic partner
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nathan-renniewaldock-ubuntu-flux-xenial.list.distUpgrade:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nathan-renniewaldock-ubuntu-flux-xenial.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nathan-renniewaldock-ubuntu-flux-xenial.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list:# deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sagemath.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nathan-renniewaldock-ubuntu-flux-xenial.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nathan-renniewaldock-ubuntu-flux-xenial.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nathan-renniewaldock-ubuntu-flux-xenial.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-security-sources.list.save:deb-src http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/java-webupd8.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nathan-renniewaldock-ubuntu-flux-xenial.list:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nathan-renniewaldock-ubuntu-flux-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nathan-renniewaldock-ubuntu-flux-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/remmina-next.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/java-webupd8.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/x2go.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/x2go/stable/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-sources.list.save:deb-src http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/puppetlabs-pc1.list.distUpgrade:# deb http://apt.puppetlabs.com bionic PC1 # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/puppetlabs-pc1.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://apt.puppetlabs.com xenial PC1
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.save:deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sagemath.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-updates-sources.list.distUpgrade:deb-src http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris.list.distUpgrade:# deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04/ ./
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/java-webupd8.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cernbox-client.list:# deb http://cernbox.cern.ch/cernbox/doc/Linux/repo/Ubuntu_16.04/ / # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-updates-sources.list.save:deb-src http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris.list:# deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04/ ./
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/remmina-next.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cernbox-client.list.save:deb http://cernbox.cern.ch/cernbox/doc/Linux/repo/Ubuntu_16.04/ /
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sstp-network-manager.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/eivnaes/network-manager-sstp/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list.distUpgrade:# deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-security-sources.list:deb-src http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cernbox-client.list.distUpgrade:# deb http://cernbox.cern.ch/cernbox/doc/Linux/repo/Ubuntu_16.04/ / # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-sources.list:deb-src http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list.save:deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sstp-network-manager.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/eivnaes/network-manager-sstp/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-updates-sources.list:deb-src http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/remmina-next.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ekozincew-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ekozincew/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ekozincew-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ekozincew/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
```

Comment: What are you running?   Some of the packages mention 16.04, others mention 19.04. Those are two different releases, and those packages should never meet (being many releases apart). I would suggest returning packages back to default for your release; if it's 16.04 then 19.04 is a number of releases away and the only upgrade path is to 18.04. If your release is 18.04 then to to 19.10 isn't actually supported anyway (except thru 18.10/19.04 with only 18.10 tested but now closed due EOL status), thus a re-install maybe easier & faster.

Comment: I'm currently running 19.04

Comment: try with --fix-missing tag

Comment: `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d` please, edit your question for output.

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libreoffice-base` to the question.

Comment: Requested outputs have been added @nobody

Comment: @N0rbert, have added the output to what you asked in edit

Comment: Don't tell me you upgrade from xenial --> disco directly.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to purge LibreOffice PPA with commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:libreoffice/ppa
```

and then proceed:

1. install upgrades to existing system with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
2. upgrade to the newest release with `sudo do-release-upgrade`